# Как собрать .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net

https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource

Скачал. Что дальше? В папке с исходниками нет решений. Нет вообще ни одного файла проекта.

Открыл в Visual Studio, как папку, так там в итоге есть классы, которые прописаны, но самих исходникво этих классов нет. Как такие вещи вообще собираются обычно?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Referencesource не является полным набором исходников для .NET Framework.

Если вам нужно что-то что вы можете сами собрать - то вам сюда:

- https://github.com/mono/mono
- https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr